# How to "orderBy" a query with a variable parameter?

Tags: doctrine, repository, dql

I'm working on Symfony4 with doctrine.
On my repository, i get informations but i can't do an order by with a variable parameter( distance between a user an many other users)

```
public function findByThemeAndDistance($theme,$distance,$user){

    $latUser=$user->getAddress()->getLnt();
    $lngUser = $user->getAddress()->getLgt();

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
   // ->select('a as activity,dist(distance) as distance' )
    ->join('a.author','u')
    ->join('u.address','add')
    ->andWhere('a.theme=:val')
    ->andWhere( '(6378 * acos(cos(radians( add.lnt)) * cos(radians(' . $latUser . ')) * cos(radians(' . $lngUser . ') - radians(add.lgt)) + sin(radians(add.lnt )) * sin(radians(' . $latUser . '))))< :distance')
    ->setParameter('distance', $distance)
    ->setParameter('val',$theme)
    ->orderBy('distance','ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

I try to get e result ordered by distance but I get This :

> Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got '1' and
>   when i erase the alais, I get This : [Semantical Error] line 0, col
>   287 near 'distance ASC': Error: 'distance' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

As the distance field does not exist on your entity you have to add the select and order by its alias

```
->addSelect('dist(distance) as distance')
->orderBy('distance','ASC')
```

Comment: Thank you fabian, but it doesn't work, Ihave this message : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 288 near 'distance ASC': Error: Class App\Entity\Activity has no field or association named distance

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabian, but I've still got an error :[Syntax Error] line 0, col 10: Error: Expected known function, got 'dist'